# error in reading a csv file

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have been facing an error while reading a `csv` file. first few lines of the line is as given below:

```
"","1.CEL","2.CEL","3.CEL","4.CEL"
"1_s_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"2_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"3_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"4_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"5_g_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"6_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"7_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
```

reading the csv.file

```
test <- read.csv(file='/home/userxyz/test.csv')
head(test)
#       X X1.CEL X2.CEL X3.CEL X4.CEL
#1 1_s_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#2   2_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#3   3_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#4   4_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#5 5_g_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#6   6_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Explicitly specifying the presence of the header.

```
test <- read.csv(file='/home/userxyz/test.file', header=T)
head(test)
#           X X1.CEL X2.CEL X3.CEL X4.CEL
#1 1_s_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#2   2_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#3   3_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#4   4_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#5 5_g_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#6   6_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

While explicitly specifying the row.names, it didn't work.

```
test <- read.csv(file='/home/userxyz/test.file', row.names=T)
#Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
#  invalid 'row.names' specification
```

`read.table`, `read.delim` functions have also been looked at.

Is the error because of special characters in the `row.names`?

Comment: `row.names` is supposed to be a vector and not boolean

Comment: @MartinDabbelJuSmelter How to specify that the file contains rownames ?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Yes. But it is present as  rownames in the actual file

Comment: For the column names, `check.names=FALSE` may also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to read in the first column as row name. Try:

```
x <- '"","1.CEL","2.CEL","3.CEL","4.CEL"
"1_s_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"2_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"3_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"4_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"5_g_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"6_at",NA,NA,NA,NA
"7_at",NA,NA,NA,NA'

read.csv(text = x, row.names = 1L)

#       X1.CEL X2.CEL X3.CEL X4.CEL
#1_s_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#2_at       NA     NA     NA     NA
#3_at       NA     NA     NA     NA
#4_at       NA     NA     NA     NA
#5_g_at     NA     NA     NA     NA
#6_at       NA     NA     NA     NA
#7_at       NA     NA     NA     NA
```

If you want to preserve exactly the header, do

```
read.csv(text = x, row.names = 1L, check.names = FALSE)

#       1.CEL 2.CEL 3.CEL 4.CEL
#1_s_at    NA    NA    NA    NA
#2_at      NA    NA    NA    NA
#3_at      NA    NA    NA    NA
#4_at      NA    NA    NA    NA
#5_g_at    NA    NA    NA    NA
#6_at      NA    NA    NA    NA
#7_at      NA    NA    NA    NA
```

---

Regarding `row.name`, read `?read.csv`:

```
row.names: a vector of row names.  This can be a vector giving the
           actual row names, or a single number giving the column of the
           table which contains the row names, or character string
           giving the name of the table column containing the row names.
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation ! `row.names = 1L` is the new approach I have learned today.